# Inner join, can't see the column

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following two dataset:

```r
t_d <- setDT(structure(list(i_phase = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 
-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), Time = c(4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001), SimulationID = c(4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), N = c(40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), discountFactor = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AgentID = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), State = c(1L, 11L, 1L, 11L, 
1L, 11L, 15L, 4L, 9L, 15L, 4L, 9L), displacement = c(1, -1, 1, 
-1, 1, -1, -5, 0, -17, -5, 0, -17), aAgentID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), aState = c(15L, 15L, 4L, 
4L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 11L), adisplacement = c(-5, 
-5, 0, 0, -17, -17, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

and

```r
dStat <- setDT(structure(list(Time = c(4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001), AgentID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), SimulationID = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), N = c(40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), 
    discountFactor = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), position = c(0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)), row.names = c(NA, 
-85L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

What I want to do is the following:

```
  dStat[t_d, vDensity_againts:= mean(i.adisplacement), on=.(position=aState,AgentID = AgentID,Time,SimulationID,N,discountFactor), by=.(position,AgentID,Time,SimulationID,N,discountFactor)]
```

However, it gives me

```r
> object 'i.adisplacement' not found
```

I don't understand, `t_d` data.table has a column names `adisplacement` and if I remove  `vDensity_againts:= mean(i.adisplacement)`, I can see that the joined data.table has a column `adisplacement` too, but when I want to do an assignment like `vDensity_againts:= mean(i.adisplacement)`, it can't see that column.

Why is this happening?

---

**Addendum:**

The ideal outcode should look like this

```r
setDT(structure(list(Time = c(4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4001, 
4001), AgentID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), SimulationID = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), N = c(40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L), 
    discountFactor = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), position = c(0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), vDensity_againts = c(0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, -17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, -17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -85L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), index = structure(integer(0), "`__AgentID`" = integer(0))))
```

Comment: You prob have to break up into 2 `[]`. The first to look up and calculate mean by your set of `by` parameters then lookup the mean back into `dstat`

Comment: @chinsoon12 even if I remove `mean`, it still can't find `i.adisplacement`

Comment: maybe something like `mDT <- t_d[dStat, on=.(aState=position, AgentID, Time, SimulationID, N, discountFactor)][,
    mean(adisplacement), .(aState, AgentID, Time, SimulationID, N, discountFactor)];
dStat[mDT, on=.(position=aState, AgentID, Time, SimulationID, N, discountFactor), 
    vDensity_againts:= V1]`. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @chinsoon12 well sort of. But this doesn't answer the question why my code doesn't work

Comment: you are trying to perform a join and a summarize action in one step. You need to columns before you can summarize.

Comment: @chinsoon12 your code doesn't result in what I want to achieve, by the way

Comment: What I want to calculate is sort of a displacement density profile such that empty spots will just have `NA` value in their `vDensity_againts` column.

Comment: how abt using a small set and showing your desired results? since the above code doesnt produce what you want

Comment: @chinsoon12 sure; give me a sec

Comment: @chinsoon12 see my addendum

Comment: i think you can just add `na.rm=TRUE` to the arguments `mean` . i.e. `mean(adisplacement, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @chinsoon12 `mean` is not the issue!

Comment: the output from the code in the comment above matches the one in addendum.

Comment: @chinsoon12 yes, it works (apparently, I didn't try it with a "clean" dataset).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly different code, aggregate-first, join-second:

```r
results <- t_d[, .(vDensity_againts=mean(adisplacement)), by=.(Time, AgentID, SimulationID, N, discountFactor, aState)
    ][ dStat, on=.(Time, AgentID, SimulationID, N, discountFactor, aState == position)
      ][, vDensity_againts := fcoalesce(vDensity_againts, 0)]

results
#      Time AgentID SimulationID     N discountFactor aState vDensity_againts
#     <num>   <int>        <int> <int>          <num>  <int>            <num>
#  1:  4001       1            4    40              0      0                0
#  2:  4001       1            4    40              0      1                1
#  3:  4001       1            4    40              0      2                0
#  4:  4001       1            4    40              0      3                0
#  5:  4001       1            4    40              0      4                0
#  6:  4001       1            4    40              0      5                0
#  7:  4001       1            4    40              0      6                0
#  8:  4001       1            4    40              0      7                0
#  9:  4001       1            4    40              0      8                0
# 10:  4001       1            4    40              0      9                0
# 11:  4001       1            4    40              0     10                0
# 12:  4001       1            4    40              0     11               -1
# 13:  4001       1            4    40              0     12                0
# 14:  4001       1            4    40              0     13                0
# 15:  4001       1            4    40              0     14                0
# 16:  4001       1            4    40              0     15                0
# 17:  4001       1            4    40              0     16                0
# 18:  4001       2            4    40              0      0                0
# 19:  4001       2            4    40              0      1                1
# 20:  4001       2            4    40              0      2                0
# 21:  4001       2            4    40              0      3                0
# 22:  4001       2            4    40              0      4                0
# 23:  4001       2            4    40              0      5                0
# 24:  4001       2            4    40              0      6                0
# 25:  4001       2            4    40              0      7                0
# 26:  4001       2            4    40              0      8                0
# 27:  4001       2            4    40              0      9                0
# 28:  4001       2            4    40              0     10                0
# 29:  4001       2            4    40              0     11               -1
# 30:  4001       2            4    40              0     12                0
# 31:  4001       2            4    40              0     13                0
# 32:  4001       2            4    40              0     14                0
# 33:  4001       2            4    40              0     15                0
# 34:  4001       2            4    40              0     16                0
# 35:  4001       3            4    40              0      0                0
# 36:  4001       3            4    40              0      1                1
# 37:  4001       3            4    40              0      2                0
# 38:  4001       3            4    40              0      3                0
# 39:  4001       3            4    40              0      4                0
# 40:  4001       3            4    40              0      5                0
# 41:  4001       3            4    40              0      6                0
# 42:  4001       3            4    40              0      7                0
# 43:  4001       3            4    40              0      8                0
# 44:  4001       3            4    40              0      9                0
# 45:  4001       3            4    40              0     10                0
# 46:  4001       3            4    40              0     11               -1
# 47:  4001       3            4    40              0     12                0
# 48:  4001       3            4    40              0     13                0
# 49:  4001       3            4    40              0     14                0
# 50:  4001       3            4    40              0     15                0
# 51:  4001       3            4    40              0     16                0
# 52:  4001       4            4    40              0      0                0
# 53:  4001       4            4    40              0      1                0
# 54:  4001       4            4    40              0      2                0
# 55:  4001       4            4    40              0      3                0
# 56:  4001       4            4    40              0      4                0
# 57:  4001       4            4    40              0      5                0
# 58:  4001       4            4    40              0      6                0
# 59:  4001       4            4    40              0      7                0
# 60:  4001       4            4    40              0      8                0
# 61:  4001       4            4    40              0      9              -17
# 62:  4001       4            4    40              0     10                0
# 63:  4001       4            4    40              0     11                0
# 64:  4001       4            4    40              0     12                0
# 65:  4001       4            4    40              0     13                0
# 66:  4001       4            4    40              0     14                0
# 67:  4001       4            4    40              0     15               -5
# 68:  4001       4            4    40              0     16                0
# 69:  4001       5            4    40              0      0                0
# 70:  4001       5            4    40              0      1                0
# 71:  4001       5            4    40              0      2                0
# 72:  4001       5            4    40              0      3                0
# 73:  4001       5            4    40              0      4                0
# 74:  4001       5            4    40              0      5                0
# 75:  4001       5            4    40              0      6                0
# 76:  4001       5            4    40              0      7                0
# 77:  4001       5            4    40              0      8                0
# 78:  4001       5            4    40              0      9              -17
# 79:  4001       5            4    40              0     10                0
# 80:  4001       5            4    40              0     11                0
# 81:  4001       5            4    40              0     12                0
# 82:  4001       5            4    40              0     13                0
# 83:  4001       5            4    40              0     14                0
# 84:  4001       5            4    40              0     15               -5
# 85:  4001       5            4    40              0     16                0
#      Time AgentID SimulationID     N discountFactor aState vDensity_againts
```

Other than the change in name from `position` to `aState` (easily) changed), this is identical to your expected output:

```r
Map(all.equal, results, expected)
# $Time
# [1] TRUE
# $AgentID
# [1] TRUE
# $SimulationID
# [1] TRUE
# $N
# [1] TRUE
# $discountFactor
# [1] TRUE
# $aState
# [1] TRUE
# $vDensity_againts
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. A quick question though: you used `aState == position` during the join. Is there a difference between `=` and `==`. Because I always use `=` and it worked so far without a problem

Comment: And I don't understand one thing: If I only do ```result <- t_d[, .(vDensity_againts=mean(adisplacement)), by=.(Time, AgentID, SimulationID, N, discountFactor, aState)
    ][ dStat, on=.(Time, AgentID, SimulationID, N, discountFactor, aState == position)]```, the `position` values that have no equivalent `aState` values are also in `result` table. Isn't this an outer join then?

Comment: I've always used `==`, perhaps just symbolically, but I really see `=` in R as assignment. The two exceptions to this appear to be in `dplyr::*_join(., by=***)` and now in `data.table`'s `[., on=***]`. And yes, by default, using `X[Y]` in `data.table` is an outer join; to get an inner join, use `X[Y, nomatch=0]`, I believe.

Comment: But regardless of its inner/outer state, this does produce the expected output. Your expected output assumes outer; that is, when you join two frames with 12 and 85 rows respectively, if your expected output is 85 rows, then it is an outer join. If you want inner, then your output (for this sample data) will be reduced to 12 rows; you can do this by adding `nomatch=0`.